# Hide certain xml using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, html

Anyway to display some li tags while hiding some using Javascript? I'm sorry if my question doesn't make sense.

Let me write my codes here.

XML:

```
    <array>
    <words>
    <name>Milk</name>
    <background>Background of Milk</background>
    <recipes>Recipes using Milk</recipes>
    </words>

    <words>
    <name>Tree</name>
    <background>Background of Tree</background>
    <recipes>NIL</recipes> or Not Applicable
    </words>
    </array>
```

Script/Javascript:

```
    <script>
    var wordsName, wordsBG, wordsRecipes, wordsCurrent;
    var wordsArray = new Array();
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"words.xml",
    dataType:"xml",
    success:function(xml)
        {
            $(xml).find('words').each(function() { //find <words> in words.xml
            wordName = $(this).find('name').text();
            wordBG = $(this).find('background').text();
            wordRecipes = $(this).find('recipes').text();
        $('<li><a href="#description">'+threatsName+'</a></li>').appendTo("#testingList");
            threatsArray.push({threatsName:threatsName, threatsBG:threatsBG, threatsCases:threatsCases});
        })
            $('#threats li').click(function(){ //li

                wordsCurrent = $(this).index()
                $('#description h1').text(threatsArray[wordsCurrent].threatsName);
                $('#name').text(threatsArray[wordsCurrent].threatsName);

                var backgroundInformation = wordsArray[wordsCurrent].wordsBG;
                backgroundInformation = backgroundInformation.split("\\n"); //to clear the line
                $('#backgroundInfo').empty(); //empty the things inside
                for (x in backgroundInformation) { //starts from zero and go to the last object
                    $('#backgroundInfo').append(backgroundInformation[x]+ '<br />');
                } //for loop CLOSE 

                var recipesInformation = wordsArray[wordsCurrent].wordsRecipes;
                recipesInformation = recipesInformation("\\n"); //to clear the line
                $('#recipesInfo').empty(); //empty the things inside
                for (x in recipesInformation) { //starts from zero and go to the last object
                    $('#recipesInfo').append(recipesInformation[x]+ '<br />');
                } //for loop CLOSE 
            })

        }
    </script>
```

Lastly, my HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="menu">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Home Page</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a href="#words" data-transition="pop"><h3>Words</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#notAvail" data-transition="pop"><h3>Not Available</h3></a> <!--Not Available-->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
    <div data-role="content"> <!--Start of DESCRIPTION content-->
        <ul data-role="listview" id="informationList">
            <li>
                <a href="#background" data-transition="pop"><h3>Background</h3></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#recipes" data-transition="pop"><h3>Recipes</h3></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!--End of DESCRIPTION content-->

</div>  <!--End of DESCRIPTION-->

<div data-role="page" id="background"> <!--Start of BACKGROUND-->
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#description" data-transition="slide" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse"></a>
        <h1>Background</h1>
        <a href="#menu" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse"></a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"> <!--Start of BACKGROUND content-->
        <p id="backgroundInfo">Not Available</p>
    </div> <!--End of BACKGROUND content-->

</div>  <!--End of BACKGROUND-->

<div data-role="page" id="recipes"> <!--Start of RECIPES-->
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#description" data-transition="slide" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse"></a>
        <h1>Background</h1>
        <a href="#menu" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse"></a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"> <!--Start of RECIPES content-->
        <p id="recipesInfo"> Recipes</p>
    </div> <!--End of RECIPES content-->

</div>  <!--End of RECIPES-->
```

As the information above, the second element in the Array, Tree, does not have any information for recipe tab, how can I prompt the page when user clicks into Tree, recipe li will hides itself?

Many thanks. It's the first time I am sending a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  You seem to be parsing XML and generating HTML dynamically using JavaScript.  In your case, maybe the easiest way is to detect the condition during parsing and add a "class" attribute to your <li> nodes.  Then define the style class somewhere in your CSS, like this:

```
<li class="no-recipe">blah blah blah</li>

<style>
    li.no-recipe {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Not sure what you're aiming for exactly, but a declarative approach is almost always better than a dynamic approach (using JavaScript).

Comment: Hi, it does help me.

But I would only want when the user clicks "Tree" , recipe will hide itself. 

What I can do now is to either hide for Milk and Tree, or show for both.

How to specific and make it only hides when Tree is being clicked.